# JQuery in external JS file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to execute some JavaScript when my html page loads. The top method populateSelectWithDates() is called, but the jquery portion does not. Any ideas?

```
function doInitialPopulation() {
    //This works
    populateSelectWithDates();

    //This does not
    $(document).ready(function() {
        alert('ok');
    //Credit to: http://www.pewpewlaser.com/articles/jquery-tablesorter
        //  Adds sort_header class to ths
        $(".sortable th").addClass("sort_header");

        //  Adds alternating row coloring to table.
        $(".sortable").tablesorter({widgets: ["zebra"]});

        //  Adds "over" class to rows on mouseover
        $(".sortable tr").mouseover(function() {
            $(this).addClass("over");
        });

        //  Removes "over" class from rows on mouseout
        $(".sortable tr").mouseout(function() {
            $(this).removeClass("over");
        });

    });
}
```

Comment: have you included `jQuery library` .Check `console` for errors.

Comment: Did you list the jquery file before your file?

Comment: Do I do the jquery import in the external js file, or in the html file?

Comment: include it before any other javascript that wants to use jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your HTML file, make sure you are including the scripts in this order:

```
<!-- first include jQuery -->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- then include your script(s) -->
<script src="YOUR_SCRIPT.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont see any use of `$(document).ready(function() {` try removing it. And let us know if alert('ok') works. Also can we see the function `populateSelectWithDates()` ?