# html + calling jquery from external js files

Tags: jquery, html

I have alot of html files that have the format

```
<head>
…
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/49714666/menuforJsFiddle2.js"></script>
…
<script>
//some script stuff 
//...
</script>

</body>
```

Whereby I can just change the contents of `menuforJsFiddle2.js` and it will affect allthe *.html files that refer to it. this is my js fiddle [example](http://jsfiddle.net/Qu3X7/13/).

Now I want to add the following js code that will add `class=”active”` to the selected tags in the menu as the user selects them

```
$(".dropdown-menu a").click(function() {
    $('li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).parents('li').addClass("active");
});
```

What is the best way to do this? 
Can I put it in the `menuforJsFiddle2.js` file as well or some other file I refer to?

I could write a script that adds it to every *.html file before the closing  tag, but I’d rather not do that. But I was thinking could I add it to a js file that I refer to already in the *.html file and somehow the *.html files will use it from there. This is what I want but not sure if/how it would be done?

NOTE:: I have looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19698320/jquery-in-external-js-file) but my question is different i think.

Comment: you should be able just add that new function to the js file and it should work, if you've already tried that, then it could be a syntax error, what does your console say?

Comment: @iamde_coder tks but how would i do that exactly?

Comment: it might be better to just wrap your code with `<script> </script>` tags at the top or bottom of the body :)

Comment: could do that but would rather put it in a external script if that was a posssible option?

Comment: then just edit that js file and put it at the very end of the file.

Comment: jaysus that was straightforward tks

Answer (score 0):

If you put the code in an closure, then you can safely add it to an existing JS file, as long as jQuery is loaded before the JS file:

```
;(function() {
    $(function($){
        // your code
    });
});
```

Also, in your code be careful to supply the context. Example: when removing the active class, all li's, even those not related to the current element will be affected.